# Which type of plants/mosses are these?

Tags: species-identification, botany

During the rainy season in India I see these miniature plants forming a light green mat over the green algae on my house's roof.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

The interesting thing is they become very green and mushy after it rains. The rest of the year in dry winters and summers they go off green (kinda brown) and survive till the next rainy season.

I suspect them to be mosses/liverworts. What do you think?

Adding some more pics-

[image: pic3][image: pic4]
The small wood piece in the above photo is around 3 cm in length. (For comparing the size)

Temperature when these pics were taken was around 35°C and it was quite humid.

Comment: Hey guys! I did a bit of research and I think I've found it! - I think it is one of the species of Funaria